# Assigning a same value in the column based on the ID of other column

Tags: r, powerquery

My dataset looks like the following,

```
Id    item   Same-item       Review
1     v1     10              Accept
2     v2     1               Accept
3     v3     4               Reject
4     v4     10              Accept
5     v5     10              null
6     v6     10              null
7     v7     5               null
8     v8     10              null
9     v9     10              null
10    v10    10              null
11    v11    10              null
12    v12    10              null
13    v13    10              null
```

I'm trying to make the Review column to "Accept/Reject" based on the "Same-item" column (which acts as id). For ex: for item v1, Same-item  =10, and Review= "Accept" in few cases, but "review" is "null" which should be "Accept"
which looks like the following

```
Id    item   Same-item       Review
1     v1     10              Accept
2     v2     1               Accept
3     v3     4               Reject
4     v4     10              Accept
5     v5     10              Accept
6     v6     10              Accept
7     v7     5               null
8     v8     10              Accept
9     v9     10              Accept
10    v10    10              Accept
11    v11    10              Accept
12    v12    10              Accept
13    v13    10              Accept
```

I tried if condition, but couldn't achieve it. Can you please guide me to reach this step. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Could `Review` be both `Accept` and `Reject` for the same `Same-item`?

Comment: `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); df %>% mutate(Review = replace(Review, Review == 'null', NA)) %>% group_by(Same.item) %>% fill(Review)` to drag the last non-NA value

Comment: @nicola Review can be both for the same item

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Same.item' `if` `any` item is 'Accept' in the 'Review' column return 'Accept' or `else` return the 'Review' values and assign (`:=`) it to 'Review'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Review := if(any(Review == "Accept")) "Accept" else Review, Same.item]
df1
#    Id item Same.item Review
# 1:  1   v1        10 Accept
# 2:  2   v2         1 Accept
# 3:  3   v3         4 Reject
# 4:  4   v4        10 Accept
# 5:  5   v5        10 Accept
# 6:  6   v6        10 Accept
# 7:  7   v7         5   null
# 8:  8   v8        10 Accept
# 9:  9   v9        10 Accept
#10: 10  v10        10 Accept
#11: 11  v11        10 Accept
#12: 12  v12        10 Accept
#13: 13  v13        10 Accept
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to overwrite the Review column, over rows that have a duplicated Same-item value, we could use this:

```
foo$Review[duplicated(foo$Same-item)] <- "Accept"
```